# Webpack caching problem - loading old resolve aliases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am working on a project that was until recently using preact. On every React-like component they were importing preact by running 'import React from 'react'' and then in their webpack.config file overwriting this using an alias:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
  react: 'preact-compat',
  'react-dom' : 'preact-compat/something'
}
}
```

I have since deleted preact and installed React. I removed these two alias lines and everything seems to work fine, except when I make changes to any files which include a react import. As soon as the website tries to reload with the changes I get a console error telling me that the module 'react' cannot be found and this error in my terminal:

```
ERROR in ./~/preact-compat/dist/preact-compat.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '..etc/node_modules/preact-compat/dist/preact-compat.js'
```

I then need to restart the webpack build before it starts working again. It's as if the imports are still being told to look for react inside preact whenever webpack tries to rebuild itself. I am guessing the problem is something to do with the aliases being cached somewhere but cannot find where exactly the problem lies.

Comment: Check if   `node_modules/.cache/webpack` (this is the default cache location) exists and remove the files there. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#cachecachedirectory

Comment: @OluwafemiSule As far as I can see it doesn't exist. I've run npm cache clean --force and still get the same problem.